# AVoid number rounding off by 10 power

Tags: bash

I am finding the difference between two columns in a file like

```
cat "trace-0-dir2.txt" | awk '{print expr $2-$1}' | sort
```

this gives me values like :

```
-1.28339e+09
-1.28339e+09
-1.28339e+09
-1.28339e+09
```

I want to avoid the rounding off and want the exact value.How can this be achieved?
FYI ,trace-0-dir2.txt contains:

```
1283453524.342134 65337.141749 10 2
1283453524.556784 65337.388047 11 2
1283453524.556794 65337.411165 12 2
1283453524.556806 65337.435947 13 2
1283453524.556811 65337.435989 14 2
1283453524.556816 65337.453931 15 2
1283453524.771522 65337.484866 16 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf` function can help get you the formatting you need. You don't need `expr` and you don't need `cat`. `awk` can do any calculation and you can invoke `awk` directly on the file.

You can alter the `20.20` to any number based on the format you are looking for.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file0
1283453524.342134 65337.141749 10 2
1283453524.556784 65337.388047 11 2
1283453524.556794 65337.411165 12 2
1283453524.556806 65337.435947 13 2
1283453524.556811 65337.435989 14 2
1283453524.556816 65337.453931 15 2
1283453524.771522 65337.484866 16 2

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '{ printf("%20.20f\n", $2-$1)}' file0
-1283388187.20038509368896484375
-1283388187.16873693466186523438
-1283388187.14562892913818359375
-1283388187.12085914611816406250
-1283388187.12082219123840332031
-1283388187.10288500785827636719
-1283388187.28665614128112792969
```

From the `man` page:

**Field Width:**

*An optional digit string specifying a field width; if the output string has fewer characters than the field width it will be blank-padded on the left (or right, if the left-adjustment indicator has been given) to make up the field width (note that a leading zero is a flag, but an embedded zero is part of a field width);*

**Precision:**

*An optional period, `.', followed by an optional digit string giving a precision which specifies the number of digits to appear after the decimal point, for e and f formats, or the maximum number of characters to be printed from a string; if the digit string is missing, the precision is treated as zero;*